# How to include email for all signers that a document has been completed?

Tags: docusignapi

I have two signers.

First signer receives templateUrl for signing. The second signer receives the document signed by frist signer through email.

Now the problem is, when the 2nd signer signs the doc, the 2nd signer receives another email that says the document has been completed. But the first signer doesnt receive it.

How can the first signer receive the email that it has been completed ?

Is there other way such that sender attribute can be added and sender receives the completed email ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the first signer an embedded signer? If so, please see this post for the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25895400/how-to-send-an-email-notifications-with-docusign-embedded-signing